# Minimum sample size for estimating proportion of finite set of binary values

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, proportion, bernoulli-distribution, finite-population

I have a finite set of data points where the number of data points has a known size $N$. The data points are binary and independent of each other, they are observations where we have either observed a property or where the property was not observed.

How large does my random sample need to be given the known and finite population size $N$ if I want to estimate the unknown proportion $P$ of true values with some confidence interval?

Comment: You need to define the power of the estimator?  At .80?

Comment: @Parseltongue What do you mean with the power of the estimator? The context is that I need to manually annotate a data set according to what points have or lack a certain property, and I want to minimize the number of data points I need to look at.